# Why does GetVolumeInformation return an int for a serial number?

Tags: winapi

How can I positively identify the physical drive AND the partition in a computer?  I've tried using VOLUME serial number from GetVolumeInformation and was shocked to see it returns a NUMBER and NOT an alpha numeric value?

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
extern static bool GetVolumeInformation(string vol, StringBuilder name, int nameSize, out uint serialNum, out uint maxNameLen, out uint flags, StringBuilder fileSysName, int fileSysNameSize);
```

I need to know that a USB thumb drive or CD or DVD or hard drive is the same physical device when it is attached to a different computer.  I also need to know that the partition or volume is the same even after a user renames it or changes the drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

What else should it return? Its just a 32 bit number that the file system assigned when it is formatted.

If you want to have it formatted like what `dir` returns, just use

```
serialNumber.ToString("X8");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing two different things.  The documentation says:

> **lpVolumeSerialNumber [out, optional]**
>
> This function returns the volume serial number that the operating system assigns when a hard disk is formatted.

So, this is the *OS assigned* serial number. It assigned it, I'm sure it knows the correct format to return it in.

It goes on to say:

> To programmatically obtain the hard disk's serial number **that the manufacturer assigns**, use the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) Win32_PhysicalMedia property SerialNumber.